# Why do we need controller when we are using "Programmable Data Plane"?

Tags: sdn

I know that a Programmable Data Plane gives us ability to customize & modify hardware for new protocols and policies.

For example we can use P4 to implement a device which acts like a hub in it's datapath.

But when we are able to apply our logic using P4 (or etc.) in the data plane, why do we need Controller & Control Plane anymore?

I mean we use controller to change switch behavior into layer-2, layer-3, firewall & etc.
And now using Programmable Data Plane we are able to do all of those using languages like P4. 
Aren't they in conflict with each other ?

Answer (score 0):

SDN provides a centralized control plane for enabling service providers to program and control the network data plane for which the OpenFlow is used as a defined communication protocol between the controller and switches. Thus SDN decoupled data plane , control plane and evolved based on assumption that the behavior of the network data path is fixed.

P4 brings in more flexibility such that the behavior of the data path can be expressed via software which would tell the switch on the way it should process packets.  P4 helps in specifying the data forwarding behavior, then populating the tables and also in auto generating the APIs that are needed to populate the tables as well due to which P4 becomes superior over OpenFlow. P4 enables SDN to be independent
of protocol, flexible to programmatically match on arbitrary packet fields that were limitations of OpenFlow.

There are many existing switches that follow the SDN architecture of separate control path and data path that use OpenFlow. Hence, OpenFlow may not become obsolete immediately due to P4 as there are numerous fixed function switch ASICs that are already deployed, and they are communicating using OpenFlow. Openflow can be still applicable for networks that are a mixture of fixed functional switches and programmable switches. In such networks, the Openfow and P4 shall function together.